# Suppose $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. What is the value of $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1-x} f(y) d y d x ?$ Use Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

- Suppose $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. What is the value of $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1-x} f(y) d y d x ?$ Again, do not forget to justify any use of Fubini's Theorem.

I evaluated by the online calculator that $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1-x} f(y) d y d x=0.$

My attempt. $\{0\leq x\leq 1, x\leq y\leq 1-x\}$ then $\{0\leq y\leq 1, 1-y\leq x\leq y\}$. Hence the integral is:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{1-y}^{y} f(y) d x d y$$

**but when I evaluate the integral, I didnt get $0$, can you help?**
But When you use Fubini's thereom to evaluated the integral, may you say how can we change boundeds of integrals?

Comment: Draw a picture of the region of integration.

Comment: @szw1710 I did it, I wrote. Edited question. Can you see above?

Answer (score 1):

Make the variable change $u=1-x$, $x=0, u=1, x=1,u=0, du=-dx$ $\int_0^1\int_x^{1-x}f(y)dydx$

$=\int_1^0\int_{1-u}^uf(y)dy(-du)=\int_1^0\int_u^{1-u}f(y)dydu=-\int_0^1\int_u^{1-u}f(y)dydu$.

Comment: Did you see my attempt?

Comment: Where did you use Fubini's theorem?

Comment: How can I use Fubini theorem now, can you help?